# Is it better to move the location of special folders in Windows 10 or should I redirect them using symbolic links?

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link

On my Windows 10 machine, the OS is installed on `C:` but it's a small disk. I have a bigger disk at `D:`.

I want special folders like Documents, Desktop, etc. to be in my `D:` drive.

I figure I have two options:

1. Change the directory in the folder properties (screenshot below)
2. Create a symbolic link: `C:\Users\me\Desktop` => `D:\me\Desktop`

I realize that #1 seems like the more "right" way but then I worry about any poorly coded application that has hard coded things like `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` because that will point to `C:\Users\me\Desktop` which doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I feel #1 seems like the "right" way because it uses an officially supported GUI method.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I somehow swapped the options in my head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolic links from C: to D: where the data remains on drive C: will not save any space on C:, so then this does not seem practical to me.

If you put the data on Drive D: and reference them as C: that does not seem practical to me.

Moving the folder(s) with Windows File Explorer will work and will physically free up space on C:  which is apparently your goal. This is (in my view and experience) your best choice.

The Microsoft method of moving Documents is well tested and works best over the longer term.

The above applies to USER Folders and NOT App folders. So just move what File Explorer allows you to move.

Work with badly behaved apps (not many really) and change to work correctly and / or eliminate their use.

You could perhaps isolate folders on D: used by such apps and provide symbolic links to C: for these

Comment: `Symbolic links from C: to D: will not save any space on C:` Huh?

Comment: Symbolic links as I know them do not keep copies on both drives. Is that wrong?  I don't think so. So if the files are kept on C:  and symbolic links allow me to reference D: file and the file sits on C:  then that is how it works, correct?  With symbolic links data exists one place or the other but not both. Correct.?  I think so.  I did make an edit to belt and suspender this.

Comment: The point of symbolic link in the OP is to relocate files on C: to D: while at the same time to allow the files to be referenced with a C: path (the original path).

Comment: That's fine and that is a way of doing things. I think it is better longer term to use the Microsoft way and (if necessary) symbolic links for badly behaved Apps.

Comment: That's a clever idea: do both. Since after doing #1, `C:\Users\me\Desktop` doesn't exist, I could create it as a symbolic link to `D:`. I will do that. Thank you!